# Text inexplicably ignores the boundaries of its container

Tags: html, css

In the slider [on the top of my page](http://goo.gl/cTFN8i) there's a green and gray element (content starts with "Mauris..."). The white text in it - both the one in green and the one in gray sub-elements - comes out on the right. Why does it do that?

I can't seem to figure it out by looking into the CSS with Firebug.

Comment: Please provide enough code to replicate the problem, simply providing a link to a website with hundreds of lines of code in is not going to help us aid you.

Comment: Don't use `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space: pre-wrap`

```css
.home_trailer_details1 h2,
.home_trailer_details2 p,
.home_trailer_details2 .button {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Pre-wrap]